# retrieving image from database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am uploading and retrieving the image from the database . image is uploaded in the database but there is problem while retrieving it on the same page.it does not show the image.it gives an exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'." in handler.ashx in line String s = (String)img;

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            SqlConnection connection = null;

     try{   

            FileUpload img = (FileUpload)FileUpload1;
            Byte[] imgByte = null;
            if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile != null)
            {
                //To create a PostedFile
                HttpPostedFile File = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                //Create byte Array with file len
                imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
                //force the control to load data in array
                File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
            }
            // Insert the employee name and image into db
            //  string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeConnString"].ConnectionString;
            connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

            connection.Open();
            string sql = "INSERT INTO Table1(ImageName,Image) VALUES(@enm, @eimg) SELECT @@IDENTITY";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enm", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eimg", imgByte);
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            Label1.Text = String.Format("Employee ID is {0}", id);

        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Handler.ashx?id=" + id;
    }
        catch (Exception)
        {    //error        }
            Label1.Text = "ERROR";
        }
    }
}
```

Handler
................

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    Int32 empno;
    if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        empno = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(empno);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

    while (byteSeq > 0)
    {
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
        byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
    }    
}


public Stream ShowEmpImage(int empno)
{

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    string sql = "SELECT Image FROM Table1 WHERE ImageID = @ID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", empno);
    connection.Open();
    object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    String s = (String)img;
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
  return new MemoryStream(data);




     //   return null;



     //   connection.Close();

}



public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}
..................
database
................
Table1 contains

```
ImageID------int
ImageName----varchar(50)
Image--------Image
```

Comment: Does the data exist in SQL Server and have you verified that your select query is indeed retrieving data?

Comment: well, now its showing an exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'" at String s=(String)img;
thanks.